# Filter list of GetMetaData to top 30 (after titel of file)?

Tags: azure, azure-synapse

i have a GetMetaData function in my pipeline which gives me the childitems of the files inside a datalake 2. There are over 100 files in there. I only need a list of the top 30 (filtered by the name) files. How can i achieve that? I have no clue. I am pretty new to azure and still learnin.

The filename looks like this:

"productx_20220301T000000.csv"
"productx_20220302T000000.csv"
"productx_20220303T000000.csv"
...
"productx_20230329T000000.csv"

I want the top 30 files after name (date). e.g.
"productx_20230329T000000.csv"
"productx_20230328T000000.csv"
"productx_20230327T000000.csv"
...

If you have an idea i would appreciate a short explanation in the best case with a picture :)

thanks everyone for the help.

Comment: which 30 files you want from the list? what is your filtered condition here? give any example for it.

Comment: I added the information. Sorry :)

Comment: you want latest 30 files as the name of the file is in date format, right? correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Not the whole filename is date format. Only a part of it like this "productx_20230301T000000.csv"

Comment: yeah, you want the last 30 days files as per this part of the file 20230301 ?

Comment: Yes thats correct ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**If you have files on every day(as per date in the file name) without missing any days in between the last 30 days**, then you can try the below approach.

First I have generated last `n` dates array in `yyyyMMdd` format using until activity. Then I have used filter activity on Get Meta data child items array. In this filter, it checks whether the `dates array` contains the **extracted date from file name of child item** or not.

**These are my sample input files:**

[image]

Here, I have filtered for **latest 4 days i.e, `20230330`,`20230329`,`20230328`,`20230327`** files.
**This is my pipeline flow:**

[image]

**dates array in `yyyyMMdd` format for 4 days:**

[image]

**This is my pipeline JSON for your reference:**

```
{
    "name": "pipeline1",
    "properties": {
        "activities": [
            {
                "name": "Get Metadata1",
                "type": "GetMetadata",
                "dependsOn": [
                    {
                        "activity": "Generates dates array until n days",
                        "dependencyConditions": [
                            "Succeeded"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "policy": {
                    "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
                    "retry": 0,
                    "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                    "secureOutput": false,
                    "secureInput": false
                },
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "dataset": {
                        "referenceName": "source_csvfiles",
                        "type": "DatasetReference"
                    },
                    "fieldList": [
                        "childItems"
                    ],
                    "storeSettings": {
                        "type": "AzureBlobFSReadSettings",
                        "enablePartitionDiscovery": false
                    },
                    "formatSettings": {
                        "type": "DelimitedTextReadSettings"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "intialize n-1 for n days",
                "type": "SetVariable",
                "dependsOn": [],
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "variableName": "daysiterator",
                    "value": {
                        "value": "3",
                        "type": "Expression"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "Generates dates array until n days",
                "type": "Until",
                "dependsOn": [
                    {
                        "activity": "intialize n-1 for n days",
                        "dependencyConditions": [
                            "Succeeded"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "expression": {
                        "value": "@equals(variables('daysiterator'), '-1')",
                        "type": "Expression"
                    },
                    "activities": [
                        {
                            "name": "Append to days array",
                            "type": "AppendVariable",
                            "dependsOn": [],
                            "userProperties": [],
                            "typeProperties": {
                                "variableName": "lastndays",
                                "value": {
                                    "value": "@formatDateTime(subtractFromTime(utcnow(), int(variables('daysiterator')), 'Day'),'yyyyMMdd')",
                                    "type": "Expression"
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "decrement and store in temp",
                            "type": "SetVariable",
                            "dependsOn": [
                                {
                                    "activity": "Append to days array",
                                    "dependencyConditions": [
                                        "Succeeded"
                                    ]
                                }
                            ],
                            "userProperties": [],
                            "typeProperties": {
                                "variableName": "temp",
                                "value": {
                                    "value": "@string(add(int(variables('daysiterator')), -1))",
                                    "type": "Expression"
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "reassign temp to daysterator",
                            "type": "SetVariable",
                            "dependsOn": [
                                {
                                    "activity": "decrement and store in temp",
                                    "dependencyConditions": [
                                        "Succeeded"
                                    ]
                                }
                            ],
                            "userProperties": [],
                            "typeProperties": {
                                "variableName": "daysiterator",
                                "value": {
                                    "value": "@variables('temp')",
                                    "type": "Expression"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    "timeout": "0.12:00:00"
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "Filter1",
                "type": "Filter",
                "dependsOn": [
                    {
                        "activity": "Get Metadata1",
                        "dependencyConditions": [
                            "Succeeded"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "items": {
                        "value": "@activity('Get Metadata1').output.childItems",
                        "type": "Expression"
                    },
                    "condition": {
                        "value": "@contains(variables('lastndays'),substring(item().name, add(indexof(item().name,'_'),1), 8))",
                        "type": "Expression"
                    }
                }
            }
        ],
        "variables": {
            "lastndays": {
                "type": "Array"
            },
            "daysiterator": {
                "type": "String"
            },
            "temp": {
                "type": "String"
            }
        },
        "annotations": []
    }
}
```

**Filter activity result array:**

[image]

If your files missing on some days, then try the below approach.

- In this case Get the child items JSON array and Give it to a Foreach. Inside Foreach use append variable activity to an array to get only dates (`int(substring(item().name, add(indexof(item().name,'_'),1), 8))`).
- Here we need to sort this array in Descending order. For sorting of array, you can follow this [approach](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/941057/azure-data-factory-sort-values-in-the-array-variab) by **@AnnuKumari-MSFT**.
- After getting sorted array of Dates, use same filter activity. Give child items of Get Meta data child items to items of filter and give the condition like this.
  `@contains(take(variables('Sorted dates array'),30),int(substring(item().name, add(indexof(item().name,'_'),1), 8)))`.